# Updating Bootstrap progress bar every second?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bit new to Javascript, and especially Ajax, and I was hoping someone might be able to help me get over one last hump for a pet project I'm working on.

I have a Ruby on Rails application using the Bootstrap API that is designed to display the status of several running threads on a web page. Each thread is represented by an ActiveRecord object, which contains, among others, a `progress` attribute, designed to be updated by my controller at certain milestones in the thread's process.

All aspects of the app are working correctly, but I need the progress bars to update dynamically as the `progress` attribute of each active thread changes. I've tried javascript's `setInterval` method, but strangely, it only seems to fire once after the page loads, rather than every second like I specified. I read a bit about ajax and I think I understand how it's supposed to work, but I'm getting a little caught up on how to adapt it to my specific application. The following is the `<div>` from my .html.erb file that contains the progress bars:

```
<% @all_active_threads.each do | active_thread | %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active span6">
            <div id="progressbar<%= active_thread.thread_id %>" class="bar" style="width: <%= active_thread.progress %>%;"><%= active_thread.campaign %></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Most of the ajax examples I've seen talk about appending a retrieved set of data to the page, or to modify a div to contain it. In my case, I have an action in my controller that retrieves an array of all of the active threads from the database, converts it to a JSON object, and renders it as json, and my javascript code retrieves this array properly. I simply need to update the "width" attribute of each bar to equal this new `progress` value. For illustrative purposes, this is what the retrieved array might look like for two active threads:

```
[ { id: 1, thread_id: 42, progress: 33 }, { id: 2, thread_id: 11, progress: 86 } ]
```

My question is, **if I have written javascript code to retrieve the array, get the progress value, and assign it to the progress bar, how can I write an ajax function to perform this operation every second?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `setInterval` method will let you execute a method in a loop. For example:

```
setInterval(function(){
  updateProgressBar();
},1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, but I actually tried the setInterval method, configured exactly as you mentioned here, but the progress bars are only updated on page load, not afterwards. This was my go-to solution too, but oddly doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Positive, it's definitely setInterval.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the code that doesn't work with setInterval?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to drum something up, but just keep in mind that I can't post the exact code, since a lot of it is reliant on a Rails controller I am currently running on a local server. I'll try to create something similar though.

Comment: Nevermind, wow, I can't believe my level of derp today. The code ran fine, but I forgot to prepend the div's id with a #. Thank you for your interest!